# How to make method B not wait for method A to finish Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

ASP.Net MVC application. Not core.
If, within the framework of one session, execute the asynchronous controller method(A) with an await. In the meantime, it will be executed to launch another controller method (B) on another page. Method B will not start executing until Method A finishes.

```
function async Task<JsonResult> MethodA()
{
  return await Task.Run(() => Get()); // > 90 000 ms
}

function async Task<JsonResult> MethodB()
{
  return await Task.Run(() => Get());
}
```

How to make method B not wait for method A to finish?

Comment: What do you mean by "In the meantime, it will be executed to launch another controller method (B) on another page", do you mean there is a new request to the server? ASP.NET runs all controller actions on their own thread. And while there is a limit to the max amount of threads, it is way larger than 2, so Method B does not wait for Method A to complete before processing

Comment: I get into method B only after the completion of method A. Maybe it's in some kind of settings? Project is old. Where be read?

Comment: I see, then the "problem" is that you are `await`ing Method A. This forces the current thread to run the method to completion and waits there. You'll want to remove that and instead start both methods like `var taskA = MethodA();` and `var taskB = MethodB();` and then wait for both to finish with `Task.WhenAll(taskA, taskB);`

Comment: The code is below. When starting from different pages in the same session.

Comment: A side note, remember that async/awit pattern does not make things run in parallel. To do that you could take a look at [TPL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl) (Task Parallel Library)

Comment: you can fire method B inside method A after method A complate

Comment: You probably shouldn't be calling a controller action from another controller action, especially without awaiting it...

Comment: Your code won't compile, and your description is not very clear. Are you saying that you have two unrelated async methods in the controller, and when you call them both at the same time from a browser, the second only starts loading after the first one completes?

Comment: you can create one result from mix of A & B return result and return one result

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code which is calling these methods

Comment: @GSerg. I received a response from your link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141795/how-to-make-asp-net-mvc-controller-methods-async

Comment: @GSerg As I understand it, SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly will affect the recording in the session in the controller (Session["name"] = "MyName"). What other problems could there be? And how right is it for heavily loaded applications.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to make MethodA and MethodB run in parallel.

```
public void Do()
{
    var taskA = MethodA();
    var taskB = MethodB();

    Task.WaitAll(taskA, taskB);
}  

private Task<JsonResult> MethodA()
{
    return Task.Run(() => Get()); // > 90 000 ms
}

private Task<JsonResult> MethodB()
{
    return Task.Run(() => Get());
}
```

Comment: It is not clear at all that this is what the OP is asking about. I would bet on https://stackoverflow.com/a/22142091/11683.

Comment: Agree that it might not be this, but I was betting on this statement: _How to make method B not wait for method A to finish?_ I'll delete it if it turns out it's not it.

Comment: GSerg is right. The link is exactly what I need. thank